# Prevent Windows 10 from using a part of physical screen

Tags: windows-10, resolution

So my work laptop has developed a few (like 10) vertical lines of dead pixels on the left hand edge of the screen ( about 100 pixels from the very left).

I would like to create a custom resolution or some other solution that gets windows 10 to render in the rest of my screen that is ok. I dont really want to do custom resolution if it involves black bars on BOTH sides of the screen, because then I'll lose 110 pixels off both sides (if the image goes in the middle).

Perhaps I could dock a bar on the left or something? Anything to convince maximized windows from not using the left hand 110px.

Any thoughts?

(Obviously replacing the laptop/screen is the right thing to do, but my company is cheap and they will only replace the laptop next year)

Any ideas are welcome, I'm slowly losing my mind here...

I have full admin rights, and the laptop is a Acer Aspire E1-572G for what it is worth...

Googling it revealed the following tool: http://www.intowindows.com/set-custom-resolution-on-windows-10/ (but im concerned with double black bars)

Comment: QQ why don't you just purchase a new screen? They are quite cheap now, you can get a 1080 monitor for less than £200.

Comment: @David Holding: OP said why... "Obviously replacing the laptop/screen is the right thing to do, but my company is cheap and they will only replace the laptop next year"

Comment: yeah, i have considered buying a screen myself out of sheer frustration, but my employer will use that as an excuse not to replace the laptop next year then.. (it's a bit hostile work environment).. so i'm looking for a technical solution.

Comment: Lol your work environment/employer surely look really bad then. Unlucky for you. An apparent solution is to put the application bar to the left instead of at the bottom. That's what I did with my Macbook Pro which had a similar problem on the left.